# Issue with targeting objects using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Tags: jquery, objective-c

I have a JQuery Carousel controlled by two images (a right image and a left image). The carousel script itself handles an event on the images to rotate the carousel upon clicking.

The client recently asked me to port the website over to an App, cheaply. Therefore I used a UIWebView which just loads the website.

I have added several extensions to it to smarten it up and to make it more suitable for app display. One of these extensions is the addition of a swipe gesture to control the carousel.

At the moment, this is my script:

```
- (void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{
    NSString *scriptInject;
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        scriptInject = @"alert('Right');$('#right-but').click();";
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        scriptInject = @"alert('Left');$('#left-but').click();";
    }
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptInject];
}
```

This handles my two gestures. What I want to happen is that a right swipe just triggers the right button to shift the carousel, I'm getting the `alert('Right')` but not getting the effect of the click. Would this be JQuery? Can you add JQuery into `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`?

I've tried `$('#right-but').trigger('click');`

Here's my HTML for those buttons:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a id="right-but"><img src="img/navbtn.png" align="left" style="z-index:94"/></a>
    <a id="left-but"><img src="img/navbtn.png" align="right" style="z-index:94"/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Carousel Jquery File and found that to control the button clicks, there is a mouseup event bound to the object as opposed to a click event.

```
$('#right-but').trigger('mouseup');
```

Fixed.